# Jquery UI autocomplete doesn't work in IE 10 and lower, but work in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have field with autocomplete. It works well in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera... but doesn't work in IE 10. JQuery and Jquery UI versions are as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://diafan/kabinet/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://diafan/kabinet/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
```

Autocomplete initializer:

```
$('#suname').autocomplete({source: getUsers,
    minLength: 3,
    select: setSearchUser,
    focus: function(){return false;},
    change: function(event,ui) {
        if(ui.item==null)
            $('#suname').val('');
    } 
});
```

and field in html document:

```
<input type="text" name="suname" id="suname" value="{{ options.uname }}" />
```

EI console dont give any bugs.

Anything doesn't happen at all. But on others browsers except IE all is just ok. Here's the function getUsers

```
function getUsers(request,response) {
    var opts={m: 'orders316',c:'get_users',uname:request.term};
    $.post('/kabinet/ajax/request.php',
        opts,
        function(data,status) {
            if(status!='success')
                return false;
            if(typeof(data.msg)!='undefined' && data.msg=='ok')
                response(data.users);
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What about other IE versions? Does it work for them? ie Is it IE10-specific? (I've added [tag:internet-explorer-10`] as a tag to the question, but maybe it should just be [tag:internet-explorer]?)

Comment: Oh, it's Internet Explorer really, thanks, at least, it doesnt work on IE 10 when I set IE9, IE8 and IE7 mode

Comment: Fair enough. You might want to re-tag the question as appropriate then. Also, please be a bit clearer about exactly what the problem is. "doesn't work" is a bit vague. Does anything happen at all? Are there any errors in the browser console? Does it call the `getUsers` or `setSearchUser` function? Maybe it's those functions that are broken? (you haven't shown them to us, so I can't tell. have you tried testing them separately or debugging them?)

Comment: Anything doesn't happen at all. But on others browsers except IE all is just ok. 

function getUsers(request,response)
{
 var opts={m: 'orders316',c:'get_users',uname:request.term};
 $.post('/kabinet/ajax/request.php',
        opts,
        function(data,status)
        {
         if(status!='success')
           return false;
         if(typeof(data.msg)!='undefined' && data.msg=='ok')
           response(data.users);
         return false;
        });
}

Comment: please edit that info into the question rather than posting it as a comment -- it's unreadable like that!

Comment: Thanks, it posted it to question